# "find missing files" doesnt find the audio strip

Tags: video-sequence-editor, edit-mode, audio

I did an edit in the VSE and then moved the source files (MOV videos) in another directory.

So i launched a "find missing files" to recover the files. Everything goes well, for the video part of the strips, instead the audio part of the videos becomes transparent and no audio is loaded or played.

I would like the audio part to be recovered as well...
Shouldnt the audio strips get extracted again from the same MOV files they took it originally from?
Is there something i'm missing?

Comment: Maybe you can use some python scripting to update the paths to your audio files dependant on their corresponding video files. And you might file this as a Bug Report?

Comment: guess i'll have a second look at it..;)